# How to make jQuery code working after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, session-state, jquery-cookie

I have following jQuery code which I want to stay active after page refresh or if user navigate to some other pages of the website:

```
$('.darkmode-button').click(function() { 
  $('.header-wrap').toggleClass('dark-header'); 
  $('.site-header__logo').toggleClass('dark-logo'); 
  $('.page-container').toggleClass('dark-body'); 
  ($.cookie('darkmode', 'enabled'));
}
); 

function changeText() {
  var x = document.getElementById("dmbutton");
  if (x.innerHTML === "Dark Mode") {
    x.innerHTML = "Light Mode";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "Dark Mode";
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573223/set-cookie-and-get-cookie-with-javascript

Comment: Can you check why this is not working? https://jsfiddle.net/websensepro/k1cvunp4/12/

Comment: I want to add Dark Mode feature in website which will work when user changes page and refreshs